# 'startActivity(android.content.Intent, android.os.Bundle)' in 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment' cannot be applied to '(android.content.Intent, int)'

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm developing my final year project about trip planner, and my app has fragments that contains other features. In FragmentPhoto, which I created to upload photo into the app has error regarding the startActivity(). The error said 'startActivity(android.content.Intent, android.os.Bundle)' in 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment' cannot be applied to '(android.content.Intent, int)'. Here is my code for the fragment.

public class FragmentPhoto extends Fragment {

```
private Button mSelectImage;
private StorageReference mStorage;
private static final int GALLERY_INTENT = 2;

public FragmentPhoto() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

    mSelectImage = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.selectImage);

    mSelectImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivity(intent,GALLERY_INTENT);
        }
    });


}


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment_photo, container, false);
}
```

}

The error kinda related to the private static final int GALLERY_INTENT = 2, since the extends is not AppCompatActivity. Is there any way to resolve this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`ACTION_PICK` send the request to installed apps(registered with this action to supply images) to allow user to pick images so to identify the request uniquely, a unique int parameter is passed which will be returned in `onActivityResult` so you have to use [`startActivityForResult`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int))

so use `startActivityForResult(intent,GALLERY_INTENT);`

Comment: i am glad that i could help